# Is there a way to select data in sql with AND conditions and with Exist Conditions

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

I am having issue querying up a query where I have 3 entries where the first entry has AA, second entry has AB and the third entry has both AA and AB.

I only want the query to return the entry with AA and AB.

I have tried the following:

```
Select * from tabl1
Where p1 in (‘AA’,’AB’)
```

Which return all three entries.

I have tried:

```
Select p1 from tabl1
Where in p1 in (‘AA’,’AB’)
Group by p1
Having p1 in (‘AA’,’AB’)
```

Returns blank.

Another one

```
Select p2 from tabl1
Where in p1 in (‘AA’,’AB’)
Group by p2
Having p2 = ‘s1’
```

Returns s1 with values AA and AB

I have also tried Exists

```
Select * from tabl1
Where exists (Select * from tabl1 where p1 in (‘AA’,’AB’)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM table1
WHERE p1 LIKE '%AA%' AND p1 NOT LIKE '%AB%'
   OR p1 LIKE '%AB%' AND p1 NOT LIKE '%AA%'
```

Answer (score 0):

It would have helped if you posted some sample data and desired result. The way I understood it, with my own sample data, you'd want to get `s3` rows because only `s3` contains both `AA` and `AB` values, and these values only.

```
SQL> with test (p1, s1) as
  2    (select 'AA', 's1' from dual union all
  3     select 'AB', 's2' from dual union all
  4     select 'AA', 's3' from dual union all  --> this
  5     select 'AB', 's3' from dual union all  --> this
  6     select 'CD', 's4' from dual union all
  7     select 'AA', 's4' from dual union all
  8     select 'AB', 's4' from dual
  9    )
 10  select s1
 11  from test
 12  group by s1
 13  having min(p1) = 'AA'
 14     and max(p1) = 'AB';

S1
--
s3

SQL>
```

- `s1` has only `AA` (missing `AB`)
- `s2` has only `AB` (missing `AA`)
- `s3` has both `AA` and `AB` and nothing else
- `s4` has both `AA` and `AB`, but also has `CD` which eliminates it